# Not able to send multiple text from SecondActivity to MainActivity's RecyclerView

Tags: android

I am able to go from MainActivity to sendactivity and enter a text which sends it to RecyclerView in MainActivity, but when I try to send another text, it goes to MainActivity but doesn't display any text.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.lovishsoftware.chinmay.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.R.attr.data;
import static com.lovishsoftware.chinmay.project.R.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private  static  final  int code=10;
    private List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ListItemAdapter itemAdapter;
    Button button1;
    String result;
    ArrayList<String> strings=new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the two
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, code );
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        if (requestCode == 10) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                result=data.getStringExtra("Text").toString();
               // itemList.toArray();
                itemList.add(result);
                itemList.toArray();
               recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(id.recyclerView);
                itemAdapter = new ListItemAdapter(itemList);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager iLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(iLayoutManager);
                //recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }


      /*  @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getText(R.).toString());
            return textView;
        }*/
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 2 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Pending";

                case 1:
                    return "Finished";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.java:

```
package com.lovishsoftware.chinmay.project;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   String[] strings=new String[10];
    Button button;
    String string;
    int i;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
                string=editText.getText().toString();
                for(i=0; i<10; i++)
                {
                    strings[i]=string;
                    break;
                }
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("Text", strings[i]);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: tried debugging your code?

Comment: Ok first, don't create your adapter and don't initialize your recycler in `onActivityResult` do it in `onCreate`. Then in your `onActivityResult` do `itemList.add(text);` and after `itemAdapter.ntofityItemInserted(itemList.size());`.

Comment: I am new to android please tell me how to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the help Raphael but it didn't work. It still displays only one text.

Comment: Update your question with what i said, and put your xml too pls.

Comment: Thank you everyone who replied. My problem is solved. Problem was in activity_main.